# Отладка кода на Питоне

Tags: python, ubuntu, отладка

Имеется проект написанный на Питоне. Я разрабатываю его на платформе Убунту, в текстовом редакторе. Какими средствами надо воспользоваться, чтобы получить возможность пошаговой отладки?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [What are good ways to make my Python code run first time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/299704/4279)

Answer (score 19):

Возможно, удобнее всего будет использовать IDE для Питона, например [PyDev](http://pydev.org) (это плагин к Eclipse) или PyCharm. Там отладчик интегрирован. Если вас не смущает консольный интерфейс отладчика, то в стандартной библиотеке Питона есть модуль [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), представляющий из себя полноценный отладчик.

Comment: А там есть возможность отладки через ssh, и имеется в виду http://hashcode.ru/questions/1078/ssh-%D0%B2-pycharm

Comment: Есть еще более удобный чем стандартный, называется pdbpp. Вот тут подробно описан http://dev.svetlyak.ru/debugger-with-blackjack/

Answer (score 11):

1. [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) , [pdb (c) habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104086/)
2. Любая IDE поддерживающая интерактивное исполение кода в debug mode с Breakpoints, например [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

и конечно же трассировка [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html), не пошагово но местами очень полезно

Answer (score 5):

Про отладчики внутри иде уже много сказано в других ответах, но вот среди консольных дебаггеров незаслуженно забыли **pudb** с псевдографическим интерфейсом (в духе борланд турбо си)