# функция которая принимает 2 параметра и возвращает список чисел от первого до второго. помогите обьяснить где я ошибаюсь

Tags: python

```
def get_range(from_number, to_number):
    numbers = []
    from_number = 1
    to_number = 10
    for num in numbers:
        while counter >= 1:
            print(counter)
            counter += 1
    return numbers

print(get_range(from_number, to_number))
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что где-то ошибаешься?

Comment: не выдается список чисел от 1 до 10

Comment: а что выдается? Что происходит при запуске кода? Выдается ошибка, верно? Почему бы не начать с чтения и исправления этой ошибки? [ask]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отладка кода на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_range(from_number, to_number):
```

принимаются параметры функции from_number, to_number

```
    from_number = 1
    to_number = 10
```

и теперь при любых входящих from_number, to_number, они превращаются  from_number = 1, to_number = 10

```
while counter >= 1:
```

counter не инициализирована до сравнения
Список numbers = [] остается пустой
Думаю нужно чуть-чуть изменить функцию

```
def get_range(from_number, to_number):
    return [number for number in range(from_number, to_number)]
```

Comment: Вы хотели сказать `list(range(...))`?

Comment: Я только чуть подправил функцию,  а Вы, @StanislavVolodarskiy, предлагаете уничтожить эту функцию напрочь, если позволите я добавлю Ваше замечание в ответ :)