# Почему не выводит приветствие ? в функции def gret_user(): после if и else?

Tags: python

```
import json

def get_stored_username():
"""Достать сохроненное имя если такое есть"""

filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        username = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    return None
else:
    return username

def get_new_username():
"""Спросить имя у пользователя"""
username = input("What is your name? ")
filename = 'username.json'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(username, f)
return username

def gret_user():
"""Поприветствовать пользователя по имени."""
username = get_stored_username()
you_name = input(f"You name {username}? (yes / no)")
if you_name == 'yes':
    print(f"Welcome back, {username}!")
else:
    username = get_new_username()
    print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")

gret_user()
```

Comment: Ну посмотри что там в username, когда из файла достаёшь

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отладка кода на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в вашем коде заключается в том, что вы не обрабатываете случай, когда `get_stored_username()` возвращает `None`. В этом случае вы пытаетесь вывести приветствие, используя None вместо имени пользователя, что приводит к ошибке.

Чтобы исправить это, вы можете проверить, равно ли значение username None, и если это так, запросить у пользователя его имя с помощью get_new_username(). Вот исправленный код:

```
import json

def get_stored_username():
    """Достать сохроненное имя если такое есть"""
    filename = 'username.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            username = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username

def get_new_username():
    """Спросить имя у пользователя"""
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    filename = 'username.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(username, f)
    return username

def greet_user():
    """Поприветствовать пользователя по имени."""
    username = get_stored_username()
    if username:
        you_name = input(f"Is your name {username}? (yes / no)")
        if you_name == 'yes':
            print(f"Welcome back, {username}!")
        else:
            username = get_new_username()
            print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")
    else:
        username = get_new_username()
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")

greet_user()
```