# Scrapy парсит не все товары

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from typing import Iterable, Any

import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.http import Response

class CatalogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "catalog"
allowed_domains = ["art-ari.ru"]
start_urls = ['https://art-ari.ru/katalog/klinker/']
pages_count = 29

def start_requests(self):
    for page in range(1, 1 + self.pages_count):
        url = f'https://art-ari.ru/katalog/klinker/?page={page}'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_pages)

def parse_pages(self, response, **kwargs):
    for href in response.css('div.image a::attr("href")').extract()[21:]:
        url = response.urljoin(href)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    item = {
        'Cсылка на товар': response.request.url,
        'Название': response.css('h1.product-header::text').get(),
        'Цена': response.css('div.oct-price-normal::text').get(),
        'Характеристики': response.css('div.attr-td::text').extract(),
        'Изображение': ''.join(response.css('li.image.thumbnails-one.thumbnail a::attr(href)').extract()),
    }

    yield item
```

По данной ссылке 29 страниц по 25 товаров, но обрабатывает данные всего 173 товаров, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: возможный дубликат: [Отладка кода на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1074/178576)

Comment: Отступы исправьте, пожалуйста. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks